# mercurial .hgrc notify hook

Tags: mercurial, push-notification, hgrc

Could someone tell me what is incorrect in my **.hgrc** configuration? I am trying to use **gmail** to send a e-mail after each push and/or commit.

.hgrc

```
[paths]
default = ssh://www.domain.com/repo/hg

[ui]
username = intern <user@domain.com>
ssh="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\plink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\key.pub"

[extensions]
hgext.notify = 

[hooks]
changegroup.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook
incoming.notify = python:hgext.notify.hook

[email]
from = user@domain.com

[smtp]
host = smtp.gmail.com
username = user@gmail.com
password = sure
port = 587
tls = true

[web]
baseurl = http://dev/...

[notify]
sources = serve push pull bundle
test = False
config = /path/to/subscription/file
template = \ndetails:   {baseurl}{webroot}/rev/{node|short}\nchangeset: {rev}:{node|short}\nuser:      {author}\ndate:      {date|date}\ndescription:\n{desc}\n
maxdiff = 300
```

Error

```
Incoming comand failed for P/project. running ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\plink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\key.pub" user@domain.com "hg -R repo/hg serve --stdio""
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
, error code: -1
  running ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\plink.exe" -ssh -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\key.pub" user@domain.com "hg -R repo/hg serve --stdio""
sending hello command
sending between command
remote: FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the steps detailled in ["AccessingSshRepositoriesFromWindows"](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AccessingSshRepositoriesFromWindows)?

If yes, you still can try:

> `Plink.exe` also has a `-batch` argument which tells plink to run non-interactively.
>   Any activity that would normally require user interaction (a new host key, for instance) will cause plink to exit immediately rather than stall.
>   **When an `ssh` operation fails, you can use the `--debug` argument to figure out what went wrong**.

Comment: I tired the above step by step...same results. 

"Server unexpectedly closed network connection"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to have the private key locally, and the public key goes on the target machine. It does seem strange that it would connect at all though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with the push not with the send email using notify extension.

If you followed the instructions correctly, maybe you have a problem if the public key and private key.

You need to edit the authorized_keys, at your server, inside .ssh folder of your user, and put your public key of your key inside this file.

The private key of your key you will use at client with pageant (Add Key button).

I recommend to use another email service instead gmail, maybe, if you send a lot of automatic email. gmail can put your ip to black list and block the emails.